# Azure AD B2C - Can we sign-in using email-id instead of UPN - local accounts only custom policy?

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm using Azure AD B2C Local Accounts Sign-in only custom policies(i.e No sign-up). I've the requirement to use email as login-id instead of UPN. I could not find any Microsoft guidelines for changing the custom policies for this requirement.

The only links I can see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-use-email-signin (Microsoft Preview) and https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email  but its not much helpful interms of what I need to change on local accounts only custom policies to sign-in using alternative login emaill-id. Could someone shed some light on this, please?

Comment: By default, AAD B2C uses email and never UPN. It’s not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT Thanks, currently I'm using local account UPN to login(For example, localb2c@<Tenant Name>.onmicrosoft.com, my customer prefers to use their corporate email-id instead of UPN. For Example, username@<company domain name>.com. We will not be connecting with on-premise AD due to security compliance. Still, login-id should match with their company email-id. I'm able to capture their company email-id on "otherMails". I 'm looking for B2C custom policy that uses OtherMails for sign-in instead of UPN. Do we have any other custom attribute to capture email input please? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When creating the user, add the corporate email into the identities collection.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-users?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-2-create-a-user-with-social-and-local-account-identities

```json
  "identities": [
    {
      "signInType": "emailAddress",
      "issuer": "yourB2C.onmicrosoft.com",
      "issuerAssignedId": "username@<company domain name>.com"
    }
  ]
```

Comment: Many thanks, let me try this approach by creating the user thru Graph API and keep you updated on this post. :) thanks again.

Comment: You are a star! It works perfectly fine. thanks.

Comment: Jas Suri, Just curious to try another approach that I've created b2c user account with sign-in type both username and email-id, I expect sso login-page to accept user name as login-id, however that displaying an error "Please enter a valid email address".  Is this something I need to change the signin custom policy as mentioned in https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/username-or-email ? Thanks.

Comment: You need to use the sample you linked in your post. The combinedsigninandsignup page only supports *either* email or username. You have to switch to a selfAsserted claimsExchange in the user journey.

Comment: Suri Thanks, sorry I was in the impression that we can make it support both. i.e. customer can sign-in either by user name or email-id. Does it not possible for same policy to support both options pls? Thanks.,

Comment: Sure you can, follow the sample, and add two identities to the identities collection, one of type email and the other of type username.

Comment: @ Jas Suri, Above Graph API approach for creating UPN with email-id signin works fine on B2C Tenant. However, when I try this approach on Azure AD default directory(i.e. Non B2c teant), throwing the error "Property userPrincipalName value is required but is empty or missing". Not sure what I am missing, could you please help me on this? Thanks.

Comment: UPN is mandatory for AAD accounts. The Graph API docs for /user show example of creating both types of users.

Comment: Got it, thanks Jas Suri.