# Azure AD B2B - Can we create the UPN with email-id instead of the domain contains ".onmicrosoft.com"?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'd like create the Azure AD B2B user with email-id For example: UPN as User1@gmail.com instead of User1@.onmicrosoft.com. I can see this is possible on B2C Tenant using Graph API as explained on the post [Azure AD B2C - Can we sign-in using email-id instead of UPN - local accounts only custom policy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68675686/azure-ad-b2c-can-we-sign-in-using-email-id-instead-of-upn-local-accounts-on1) However, this approach doesn't work getting an error for B2B tenant.

Is there any way to achieve this using Azure B2B portal OR Graph API please? Thanks.

Comment: this is not possible in b2b collaboration, we can invite Gmail account user as a guest user through portal or API https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/external-identities/add-users-administrator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the UPN with the email id of the verified domain in the Azure AD B2B.

For example, we can add the custom domain in Azure AD and make it as primary. Now, we can create users with UPN suffix as your custom domain.

[image]

If we cannot verify the domain or to use some personal mail accounts like gmail or yahoo, we can invite the user to Azure AD.

But the UPN seems to be similar to this :

[image]

Also, we can enable Sign-in to Azure AD with email as an alternate login ID.

**Reference** : [Sign-in to Azure AD with email as an alternate login ID | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-authentication-use-email-signin)

Comment: Excellent, thanks Ramarao!